# Is a symlink to a directory a file or a directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, symbolic-link

I have several commands that remove files and directories. One of them deleted a symlink that was pointing to a directory.

It raised the following question: which command removed it? The one that removes files or the one that removes directories?

In other words: **what is a symlink to a directory: a file or a directory?**

Example of such command:

```
find www -type f ! -name ".htaccess" -delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically a [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), containing a string with a reference to another filesystem object, but it is notable that symlinks have somewhat different properties than most files. for instance you can deny write on the symlink, while retaining write on the target file. write privileged on the link would allow you to delete the link, even if you don't have write on the target file. for some operations the link is transparent, and for others it is opaque, so there is definitely some filesystem abstraction involved in their inner workings.

you may want to check your auth log to determine what command deleted it.

Edit:
Since you are so interested in the find command, note that find does not process symlinks at all. see here:

```
Minty17 ~ $ mkdir test
Minty17 ~ $ cd test
Minty17 ~/test $ mkdir testdir
Minty17 ~/test $ touch testdir/testfile1.txt
Minty17 ~/test $ ln -s testdir testlink
Minty17 ~/test $ ls
testdir  testlink
Minty17 ~/test $ find -type f | grep testlink
Minty17 ~/test $ find -type d | grep testlink
Minty17 ~/test $ find -type d 
.
./testdir
Minty17 ~/test $ find -type f 
./testdir/testfile1.txt
Minty17 ~/test $ cd ..
Minty17 ~ $ rm -rf ./test
```

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to such logs. There is no way to know which of `find -type f` or `find -type d` would remove a symlink?

Comment: why are you so fixated on the find command? you could easily set up a test to find out whether symlinks are transparent or opaque to `find -type `.

Comment: Erm because I need to edit the find command in my cron that keeps deleting my symlink every night :) Since it's not my server I don't want to do the messy solution of editing all the commands

Answer (score 1):

It is a *special file*, one of several that [UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types), way before Linux, implemented. Besides files and directories, the other filetypes are *links, named pipes, sockets, device files (further split into character and block devices)*. I tell you this in order to stress that in *Nix not everything is either a directory or a file: there are these other funny characters as well.

It is used in two different ways: first, to provide to multiple programs a single version of a file, so that any modification needs to be done just once and then becomes immediately available to all programs.

Second, to provide a given functionality through one of many of different equivalent programs. For instance, a command like *awk* is part of any *Nix system, but there are many different versions of it, with slightly different names. In fact,

```
 $ whereis awk
 awk: /usr/bin/awk /usr/bin/X11/awk /usr/share/awk /usr/share/man/man1/awk.1.gz
 $ file /usr/bin/awk
 /usr/bin/awk: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/awk' 
 $ file /etc/alternatives/awk
 /etc/alternatives/awk: symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gawk'
 $ file /usr/bin/gawk
 /usr/bin/gawk: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=76bb13aac7e212164bd6e0d7b8a5d92db44543c9, stripped
```

The real file is *gawk*, but in order to allow me to ignore all the equivalent choices I have, the symbolic link *awk* has been set to provide the use of *gawk*, in a way totally transparent to me.

In order to avoid the usual TL;DR, I will just let the above link provide further info, if you care.

EDIT:

To find all symbolic links, you can use:

```
  find /path/to/directory/ToBeSearched -type l
```

To remove them all,

```
  Find /path/to/directory/ToBeSearched -type l -exec rm {} \;
```

or some such variations (there are endless).

Comment: So will it be removed by `find -type f` or `find -type d`?

Comment: Ah ok I cannot find that information in the answer. I don't understand what removes that symlink then I'll have to dig deeper :/

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli Please see my Edit